# How to handle button click events dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

[image]

All this data are come dynamically. There is a button **Manage** in every card. this also created dynamically.

**for example :**
When I click on manage button of **user** then it should be navigate to that component then how its identify that which manage button is clicked & where to navigate

I created multiple dynamic mat cards for which I take data from server side .For each card I have a  manage button which is also dynamic.
SO when I click to User card manage button I want navigate to user component ,when I click to log card manage button I want to navigate log component and so on.

In one variable I store the all titles, When I take a for loop to that cards title & compare every cards key with specific string which is equal to that cards title (ex.if i have user card then i compare key=='USER') then it navigates to user and log components too and so on.

Comment: Can you include some HTML code with the rendering of these cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is pass as argument of the button the "title" of the card

```
<div class="card">
{{title}}
<button (click)="manage(title)">Manage</button>
</div>
```